# SAS Macro how to define part of the word?

Tags: macros, sas

My program is like this:

```
data a;
input p1-p3;
datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
;
%macro hello(version=);
proc print data=a;
where &version2=5;
run;
%mend hello;
%hello(version=p)
```

How can I find where p2=5?

Comment: Hello! You might want to format your code a little better by using more conventional spacing so it can be easier for others to read. Cheers.

Comment: You need to delimit macro resolutions with a period: `where &version.2=5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sasfrog has the correct answer in the comment. Simply change `where &version2=5;` to `where &version.2=5;` and you're golden. The reason for this is that SAS thinks &version2 is actually the name of the macro variable, but it can't find a macro variable named &version2! Putting the period there tells SAS "that's the end of the macro variable name, so treat everything after it as your normally would."

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to remove the 2 from code and add it to the macro call, like this:

```
%macro hello(version=);  
  proc print data=a;  
    where &version=5;  
  run;  
%mend hello;  
%hello(version=p2)
```